# Operation matrix with user user input

Tags: python

I have

```
import numpy
    B = numpy.array([[1, 2], [5, 8]])
    C = numpy.array([[13, 14], [15, 16]])

def entry(matrixA, matrixB, i, j):
    i = i - 1
    j = j - 1       
    matrixX = matrixB.copy()
    matrixX[i][j] = matrixA[i][j]
    return matrixX
    
e = entry(B, C, p, u)
print(e)
```

How to create e with `p= 1,...m`, `u =1,...,n` (n,m based user input) ?

Like for  `p=1, u=1 e=?`
p=1, u=2 e=?
p=2, u=1 e=?...  etc
Thank you

Comment: do you want to create nxm matrix or what? what will be the elements? will the elements be taken through input also? what is that entry function intended to do?

Comment: Consider to add `matrix` tag mark it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? If I understood correctly, you want to iterate over the different combinations of those numbers `p` and `u` until `m` and `n` (user input).

```
import numpy

B = numpy.array([[1, 2], [5, 8]])
C = numpy.array([[13, 14], [15, 16]])

def entry(matrixA, matrixB, i, j):
    i = i - 1
    j = j - 1       
    matrixX = matrixB.copy()
    matrixX[i][j] = matrixA[i][j]
    return matrixX
    
m = 2
n = 2

for p in range(1, m+1):
    for u in range(1, n+1):
        e = entry(B, C, p, u)
        print(e)
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do I operate the result?
For example, I want to multiply matrix B by every e? example: matrix B multiplied by e for p=1, u=1 and then multiplying B by e for p=1,u=2, ... and so on?

Comment: You mean matrix inner product? Because B and e are both matrices. What would be your final result look like? One single matrix? You can try `e = numpy.inner(B, e)` after computing e inside the for loops.

Comment: I mean that when we get matrices e with p=1 and u=1, call it e(11) or e with p=1 and u=2, call it e(12). So we get some e(pu) matrices. how to operate one of e(pu) with matrix B or C? for example I want to product e(11) by B and e(12) by C

Comment: You would do that with `numpy.inner(e, B)` or `numpy.inner(e, C)` inside the loop (after computing the corresponding matrix `e`). Now if you need to save each different matrix to make some other calculations, you can save them in an empty list, but that would be a completely different question you originaly asked.

Comment: how to save them in an empty list? from e, I want to get 4 different matrices. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is, you want to get such a matrix which is a copy of matrixB but the values in indexes from `(0,0 to n-1)` to `(m-1,0 to n-1)` will be taken from corresponding indexes of matrixA.

So, inside entry function, just do:

```
def entry(matrixA, matrixB, i, j):
    matrixX = matrixB.copy()
    for indexX in range(i):
        for indexY in range(j):
            matrixX[indexX][indexY] = matrixA[indexX][indexY]
    return matrixX
```